# . How do you prevent/fix callback hell?

Tags: node.js

Trying with Modularize – split the callbacks into smaller, independent functions that can be called with some parameters then joining them to achieve desired results.

```
r logError = function(error){
    if(!error){
      console.log("success!!");
    }else{
      console.log("error");
    }
},

updateTransaction = function(t){
    query("UPDATE transactions SET value = " + (t.value*0.1) + " WHERE id=" + t.id, logError);
},

handleTransactions = function(transactions){
    transactions.each(updateTransaction);
},

handleClient = function(id){
    query("SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE clientId=" + id, handleTransactions);
};

query("SELECT clientId FROM clients WHERE clientName='picanteverde';",handleClient);
```

You can also use Promises, Generators and Async functions to fix callback hell

Comment: I have applied such way

Comment: *You can also use Promises, Generators and Async functions to fix callback hell* - yes, you can. What's the question?

Comment: Question is I've applied such code but it's quite confusing, need another way to simplify the code

Comment: *need another way* - considering that you already know that promises and async/await can help, what did you try? The question is unanswerable because the case totally depends on what `query` is. This snippet lacks the context. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

the most obvious approach is to use `Promises` ,i.e make your functions modularised and return `promises` .Another very hot and amazing approach is using `async/await` .Visit [this](https://medium.com/@tkssharma/writing-neat-asynchronous-node-js-code-with-promises-async-await-fa8d8b0bcd7c) article which shows how they are used.